# Original Estimates in Azure DevOps - Max value?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, estimation

Our evolution of using DevOps is continuing (slowly but surely). One thing we've noticed is that some people are trying to but excessive estimates in for their time, but what we really want to be encouraging is for people to be breaking work down into multiple tasks.

Is there a way that we can set our DevOps work items to only accept a maximum value?  I've had a look at the 'rules' and there doesn't seem to be anything there to let us do this, and because it's an out of the box field I don't **think** we can put a value limit against it.

I suppose what I want to understand is whether it would be possible to do this in some way?  Could I do something with the existing 'Original Estimate' field or would I have to create a new custom field to have any chance of preventing people from putting in 100 hours for something that's actually more like 2?

Comment: If you are also using Boards, you could highlight tasks which work items where the original estimate is higher than a certain value. This would not prevent setting these values, but rather encourage the users to put in lower values. Beware that this might not really help the underlying issue: People must be convinced of the benefits of splitting up tasks, otherwise they will just work around the tooling. Like always putting in the maximum value or not putting in the actual work hours.

Comment: Thanks Alex, I like the sound of that. Totally understand what you're saying and I think there are more people fudging the figures as it stands for a combination of reasons - poor training, poor process(es), and/or laziness. I find it a bit bewildering that a group of people who think themselves to be progressive, can't get the basics right. Highlighting seems like a really good idea though. It means they have no excuse to say they've done something daft, and also lets the Project Team and potentially even Senior Managers know. Will have to give highlighting a try and see what I can do with it

Comment: Glad you like the idea. I have added an answer based on the content of my comment in case you decide to go with that approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are also using Boards, you could highlight work items where the original estimate is higher than a certain value. This would not prevent setting these values, but rather encourage the users to put in lower values.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/boards/customize-cards?view=azure-devops
[image: example configuratoin]

Beware that this might not really help the underlying issue: People must be convinced of the benefits of splitting up tasks, otherwise they will just work around the tooling. Like always putting in the maximum value or not putting in the actual work hours.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way that we can set our DevOps work items to only accept a
> maximum value?

I am afraid that setting the value limit for the Original Estimates field is currently not supported.

As workaround,  you could need to create a custom field of type `Picklist`, and then specify the available values in the picklist.

[image]

You could add your request for this feature on our [UserVoice](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21) site , which is our main forum for product suggestions.After suggest raised, you can vote and add your comments for this feedback. The product team would provide the updates if they view it.

Comment: Looks like there's an issue with the site certificate when I try and click your link Hugh.  I thought it may be the case that we'd need to create another field, and replace the original estimate field with something else. I suppose DevOps is essentially scratching the surface at the moment so maybe it'll get tweaks like this at some point.